# Overriding template via the theme does not work in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, overriding

I'm creating a custom Wordpress/woocommerce theme for a client based on FoundationPress. For some reason I can't override `taxonomy-product_cat.php`. I can override this file with other themes like twenty-nnn or Storefront. I spend half a day finding a answer with no luck.

At the end I stripped down the Foundationpress theme to just a index.php + style.css. I cleared the caches, recreated the template files in Woocommerce > status > tools. I disabled all the third party plugins except Woocommerce.

But it still refuses to override my category template. I'm stuck here. Can somebody please give me some directions?

In 'Woocommerce > status' I see this template marked as overridden. But It doesn't show on the frontend.

Comment: You need to create woocommerce folder in your theme

Comment: I did that. But I finally found a solution. You have to declare "add_theme_support" in your functions.php. So:

`add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );`

This declaration did the trick. After that, my custom Woocommerce templates finally gets recognized.

Comment: Good...Happy to hear that !!

Comment: Hi @loictheaztec I just move the answer to the right field.

Comment: @NormanvanderMull Nice thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

Solved:

I finally found a solution.

You have to declare "add_theme_support" in your `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

After that, my custom Woocommerce templates finally gets recognized.

Strangely enough it's not mentioned clearly in the docs on the Woocommerce website.

Comment: Thank you I had the same issue, so incredibly stupid. Spent several hours on this as well.

Comment: Fixed for me, too. I should also note that I use underscores, and within the functions.php of that starter theme, there is an action/function that handles other add_theme_support() functions. Therefore, I added it in there, like this: add_action('after_setup_theme', 'jwd_setup'); Within jwd_setup(), I added add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' ); This seems to be working fine.